# ubuntu PostFix + Dovecot mail server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot

/log/mail.log

```
Jun 23 10:38:05 mail postfix/smtpd[60639]: connect from mail.faisal.asia[127.0.0.1]
Jun 23 10:38:05 mail postfix/smtpd[60639]: disconnect from mail.faisal.asia[127.0.0.1]
Jun 23 10:38:06 mail postfix/smtpd[60639]: connect from unknown[87.109.16.179]
Jun 23 10:38:06 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=87.109.16.179, lip=100.86.126.126, session=<IZlLcH78+ABXbRCz>
Jun 23 10:38:06 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=87.109.16.179, lip=100.86.126.126, session=<j6dLcH78UQBXbRCz>
Jun 23 10:38:06 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=87.109.16.179, lip=100.86.126.126, session=<KLZLcH78AABXbRCz>
Jun 23 10:38:06 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=87.109.16.179, lip=100.86.126.126, session=<SvxLcH78qABXbRCz>
Jun 23 10:38:06 mail postfix/smtpd[60639]: disconnect from unknown[87.109.16.179]
Jun 23 10:38:11 mail postfix/smtpd[60646]: connect from unknown[87.109.16.179]
Jun 23 10:38:11 mail postfix/smtpd[60646]: disconnect from unknown[87.109.16.179]
Jun 23 10:38:23 mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=87.109.16.179, lip=100.86.126.126, TLS, session=<odBMcX78OQBXbRCz>
Jun 23 10:38:24 mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=87.109.16.179, lip=100.86.126.126, TLS, session=<EqxZcX78YABXbRCz>
```

/log/mail.err

```
Jun 23 06:03:26 lpowers postfix/smtpd[51650]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 23 06:56:16 mail postfix/smtpd[52303]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 23 07:21:43 mail postfix/smtpd[52754]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 23 08:54:01 mail dovecot: auth: Error: read(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: EOF
Jun 23 08:54:01 mail dovecot: auth: Error: net_connect_unix(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: Permission denied
Jun 23 08:56:02 mail dovecot: auth: Error: read(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: EOF
Jun 23 08:56:02 mail dovecot: auth: Error: net_connect_unix(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: Permission denied
Jun 23 10:35:53 mail postfix/postmap[60629]: fatal: usage: postmap [-Nfinoprsvw] [-c config_dir] [-d key] [-q key] [map_type:]file...
Jun 23 10:45:03 mail postfix[60676]: fatal: usage: postfix [-c config_dir] [-Dv] command
Jun 23 10:45:29 mail postfix[60678]: fatal: usage: postfix [-c config_dir] [-Dv] command
```

Dovecot Configuration: (dovecot -n)

```
root@mail:/var/log# dovecot -n
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.13.0-29-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
first_valid_uid = 150
last_valid_uid = 150
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_uid = vmail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@faisal.asia
protocols = " imap pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}

root@mail:/var/log# dovecot --version
2.2.9
```

PostFix Configuration:

```
root@mail:/var/log# postconf -n
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = no
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination =
myhostname = mail.faisal.asia
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/hostname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
```

I'm unable to create an email account in email client. It gives an authentication error. when I'm sending an email from telnet then email send properly.

Can you please guide me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to add this line to your main.cf `queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix` and then restart postfix.

Conversely, it might be worth attempting to put the entire path to the `private/auth` file,  if the first method does not work.